# How to resize Tweet embed

Tags: html, css, embed

I have three Twitter embeds on my codepen site found here https://codepen.io/Benmuiruri/pen/LYyYbVv. However, the three embeds are not the same height and I can see the difference in height from the iFrame.

I have also attached a photo of the difference below [image: IFrame height difference]

Here is the code

```html
<div class="tributes-wrapper">
        <div class="tribute-copy">
            Twitter embed
        </div>
        <div class="tribute-copy">
            Twitter embed

        </div>
        <div class="tribute-copy">
            Twitter embed

        </div>
```

How would I use CSS to make sure all the`<div class="tribute copy">` have same height?

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://nimb.ws/ELTmQg

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to resize.  The middle embed is longer than the others. How can I ensure that the twitter iframe fits into the dimentions of my div

Comment: I don't know but have you inserted the embed code or the code generated after that? Because the embed code should work as you have shown in the output.

Comment: The code snippet in the question is not the full code because I had to remove twitter's shortened urls. But in the codepen link you can see the full code with the embed code included. 

The embed is working fine. I am just wondering how can I ensure that the embed fits into the dimensions of my div. So that all three have the same size

Comment: Each of the embeds is showing exactly one tweet. Could you describe what you mean by 'the same height' - they are just not of the same height naturally so do you want to center the short ones vertically, or show part of the next tweet on the short ones or....?

Comment: Hi @AHaworth the embeds are showing three different tweets (As shown in the screenshot). If you click on the codepen you can see the actual tweets. What I mean by the same height is I do not want the middle tweet to be longer than the other two. 
I get what you mean by they are not the same height naturally. Hence my question, is it possible to format my divs such that when I load in 3 or 6 embeds, they will all have the same dimensions? If you check the codepen, I want the embed section to be symetric like the legacy section above it.

Comment: The question is, what do you want it to look like? The content doesn't have the same height, so should it be cut off or should the short ones have white background or do you want to show a bit of the next tweet.

Comment: @AHaworth I would like it to be symetric like the legacy section above the embed section. The legacy section uses images so it is easy to have them all symetric. However, since the content have different heights, can I achieve something similar....where all have the same height? I think one way would be to cut off the long embed and have a scroll on it, correct?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do something as the tweets are of differing sizes, and obviously at run time you don't know what their relative heights will be in advance. Cutting it off and having a scroll would be one way. They will of course be visually different, the longer tweets won't show any image, and some tweets won't have an image at all and some will be very short. Personally I'd go for a reasonably long size and with a white background rather than just accommodate the shortest possible tweets.